# Proof Bell-Number $B(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}B(k)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bell-numbers

Let's say that $B(n)$ (the Bell number) is the number of ways to split $\{1, \ldots ,n\}$ in non-empty blocks. Prove that, for $n \geq 1$:
$$B(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}B(k)$$
I don't really know how to hadle this. My first idea was doing this with a logic reasoning, since we know that:

$1)B(n)$=number of partitions of $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$

$2)B(k)$=number of partitions of $\{1,\ldots ,k\}$

$3)
\begin{pmatrix} n-1 \\ k\end{pmatrix}$ = number of ways of taking $k$ elements from $\{1,\ldots ,n-1\}$

But I am not sure this leads to a solution. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Hint: Consider the cardinality of the block that contains $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The [method of distinguished element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_distinguished_element) can be applied. The result is trivial for the singleton set and the empty set, so we will prove that $$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}B_k}$$ for all integers $n\ge 1.$ The distinguished element is $n+1.$ This element inhabits a set of $k+1$ elements in a partition for some $k\in [n]^{*}=\{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}.$ There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose the other $k$ elements of the set, and the remaining $(n+1)-(k+1)=n-k$ elements can be partitioned in $B_{n-k}$ ways. By the symmetry of Pascal's triangle, we get $$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}B_{n-k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{n-k}B_{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}B_k}.$$

The proof is also described in the Wikipedia article on [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Summation_formulas).